# /bin/sh: cc: command not found for Perl module

Tags: gcc, makefile, gd, cc

Hi I'm trying to install perl module GD-2.46.

After `perl Makefile.PL --ignore_missing_gd`,
I was trying to `make`
Then I got the error:

```
 cc -c  -I/project/umw_robert_brown/guang/breakdancer/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/gd -Wformat=0 -O2   -DVERSION=\"2.46\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.46\" -fPIC "-I/share/pkg/perl/5.18.1/lib/5.18.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"  -DHAVE_JPEG -DHAVE_FT -DHAVE_XPM -DHAVE_GIF -DHAVE_PNG -DHAVE_ANIMGIF GD.c
    /bin/sh: cc: command not found
    make: *** [GD.o] Error 127
```

It seems to me GCC compiler is missing, so I tried

```
make CC='/share/pkg/gcc/4.9.2/bin/gcc'
```

So for the error above, it's solved (gcc could be found):

```
/share/pkg/gcc/4.9.2/bin/gcc -c  -I/project/umw_robert_brown/guang/breakdancer/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/gd -Wformat=0 -O2   -DVERSION=\"2.46\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.46\" -fPIC "-I/share/pkg/perl/5.18.1/lib/5.18.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"  -DHAVE_JPEG -DHAVE_FT -DHAVE_XPM -DHAVE_GIF -DHAVE_PNG -DHAVE_ANIMGIF GD.c
```

But I got another error complaining

```
LD_RUN_PATH="/project/umw_robert_brown/guang/breakdancer/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib" cc  -shared -O2 -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector GD.o  -o blib/arch/auto/GD/GD.so     \
       -L/project/umw_robert_brown/guang/breakdancer/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib64 -lgd -lfreetype -ljpeg -lpng -lz -lm -lX11 -lXpm     \

/bin/sh: cc: command not found
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/GD/GD.so] Error 127
```

I'm just so confused, since the first `cc` could be found, why couldn't find the second?
Thx

Comment: Why don't you use the CPAN shell to install modules?

Comment: Does the Makefile hardcode `cc` instead of using the variable in the second instance? As a quick workaround, regardless, maybe symlink your `gcc` to e.g. `$HOME/bin/cc`, and make sure `$HOME/bin` is in your `PATH`, obviously.